# Make a UICollectionView in UITableViewCell programmatically in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios-autolayout

I have a subclass of tableview cell which needs to have a UICollectionView inside it. I am now facing issues while trying to add a UICollectionView. It is letting me add a new UICollectionView but I am unable to set its constrains. Below is my code for doing the same:

```
// Add Collection
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)

    collectionProducts = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)

    contentView.addSubview(collectionProducts)

    let leadingColConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: collectionProducts, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leadingMargin, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leadingMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let trailingColConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: collectionProducts, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.trailingMargin, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.trailingMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let topColConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: collectionProducts, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: lblHeader, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 62)
    let bottomColConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: collectionProducts, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 55)

    contentView.addConstraints([leadingColConstraint,trailingColConstraint,topColConstraint,bottomColConstraint])
    collectionProducts.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Am I missing anything? I am a relatively late mover to Swift and also relatively new to creating the cells programmatically. I can easily do the same using nib or storyboard, but I am stuck here. Kindly help be out.

Comment: hay @Mayank Pahuja check this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RxEGlpeONOc its help full

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can avoid all those constraints, just add Visual Format Language constraints, like this

```
contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": collectionProducts]))
contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[label][v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["label": labelHeader,"v0":collectionProducts]))
```

And keep the `collectionProducts.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false`

Comment: Thanks! This works great. VFL is the way to go. Just made the changes to my code accordingly and learned a few things about VFL along the way. Thanks so much and it saved me. BTW any idea why it wasn't working with the constraints that I was using? Since I have a few labels added with the same constrains and are working fine, but somehow not the Collection View. Thanks Again!

Comment: maybe in the attribute of the `bottomColConstraint` you put ´top´ instead of ´bottom´

Comment: @MayankPahuja no worries! happy to help!

Comment: Edu thanks for pointing that out. Writing "top" in place of "bottom" was indeed the problem. I have been looking at my code for so long and was not able to figure it out. Could not see such a straightforward mistake staring at me.

Comment: @MayankPahuja happens all the time haha